# Equivalent of Rust's match statement in Java

Tags: java, rust

I can mostly understand the following code, but please tell me the meaning or the equivalent in Java

```
while !self.eof() {
    match self.next_char() {
        '#' => {
            self.consume_char();
            selector.id = Some(self.parse_identifier());
        }
        '.' => {
            self.consume_char();
            selector.class.push(self.parse_identifier());
        }
        '*' => {
            // universal selector
            self.consume_char();
        }
        c if valid_identifier_char(c) => {
            selector.tag_name = Some(self.parse_identifier());
        }
        _ => break
    }
}
```

What is the purpose of this code?

```
c if valid_identifier_char(c) => {
    selector.tag_name = Some(self.parse_identifier());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code (specifically, it's called a match arm) has three relevant parts: `c`, `if valid_identifier_char(c)` and the block `{ selector.tag_name ... }`

The `c` is the pattern: that is, it tells the compiler what values to match against, and how to destructure them.  All the previous arms used literal patterns, so they simply match against the specific character and don't capture anything.  *This* pattern has a variable binding `c`, which means it will match *anything*, and whatever it matches should be bound to a variable `c`.

> As an aside: you can have patterns like: `Some(x)`, which indicate that the arm should match an `Option` whose value is a `Some`, and that the *contents* of that `Some` should be bound to a variable `x`.

The `if ...` is known as a condition guard.  All that does is place an additional restriction on the arm.  It makes it so that, *irrespective* of the pattern and the value being matched, the arm as a whole cannot match *unless* the condition evaluates to `true`.  So, whilst the pattern `c` will match any value, the arm as a whole will not match unless `valid_identifier_char(c)` *also* evaluates to `true`.

Finally, the block is simply the code that will be executed if the arm matches.

I'm not big on Java, but I believe the code to be *roughly* equivalent to:

```
// Actually should be "unsigned long", but Java.
long _temp = this.next_char();
switch _temp {
    case 35:
        // First branch...
        break;

    case 46:
        // Second branch...
        break;

    case 42:
        // Third branch...
        break;

    default:
        long c = _temp;
        if valid_identifier_char(c) {
            // Fourth branch...
        } else {
            // Final branch...
        }
        break;
}
```

In general, however, `match` expressions don't always map nicely to a switch, *especially* if they do complex destructuring.